# Convert QLPreviewRequestRef to QLThumbnailRequestRef

Tags: objective-c, quicklook

Is it possible to convert or typecast the one to the other?

I want to do this because my QuickLook generator is doing the same thing for both thumbnails and previews.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are fundamentally different. You'll have to wrap them in your own kind of object and chose the API to answer the request accordingly.